Tooltip implementation for Google chat(hangouts) card v2 template button
We are having a set of buttons in cardV2 template in hangout chat we need to show some button related information to user when user hover over the button using tooltip or other way. Can you guide us and provide script on how to show information to user when user hover over a button
this week and we expect that tooltip is shown for button
